# Is there a nice way to filter a list using streams and get a list of the items or null if no item passed the filter?

Tags: java, filter, java-8, java-stream, collectors

Currently I do:

```
List<MyObj> nullableList = myObjs.stream().filter(m -> m.isFit()).collect(Collectors.toList());
if (nullableList.isEmpty()) {
    nullableList = null;
}
```

Is there a nicer way? Something like Collectors.toListOrNullIfEmpty()?

Comment: It is not a good practice to use null as a legitimate value.  In particular, null should never be used as a synonym for an empty array, collection or map.  Using an empty List will allow other code to omit null checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not actually sure you have to do that way. Sometimes people write horrible code trying to make it simpler. I'd leave this case with additional `if` after stream like in your code. But you can find a code you looking for below c:

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
        List<Integer> nullableList = list.stream()
                .filter(m -> m > 2)
                .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                        Collectors.toList(), filtered -> filtered.isEmpty() ? null : filtered
                ));
        System.out.println(nullableList);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is not such thing, you *could* do a helper method that basically will:

```
.collect(
        Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.toList(),
            x -> x.isEmpty() ? null : x)
);
```

But you are asking for trouble here. Just return that empty List instead of a `null`, unless you want *callers* to eventually hate you.

If you really really want such a Collector:

```
static class PlzDont<T> implements Collector<T, List<T>, List<T>> {


    @Override
    public Supplier<List<T>> supplier() {
        return ArrayList::new;
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<List<T>, T> accumulator() {
        return List::add;
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<List<T>> combiner() {
        return (left, right) -> {
            left.addAll(right);
            return left;
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Function<List<T>, List<T>> finisher() {
        return x -> x.isEmpty() ? null : x;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return Set.of();
    }
}
```